# Why isn't python reading the if statement inside the for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm doing a project for my coding class where we have to make a love calculator which has to include a list and the for loop. It doesn't want to read the if loop no matter what and I've even added a debugger to see if it was just the t+=1 that wasn't running but nope. I can't understand for the life of me why it doesn't want to run properly so any help is appreciated.

```
x = input('Enter your name:\n');
y = input('Enter other\'s name:\n');
t = 0
love = ['l', 'o', 'v' , 'e'];
for i in x:
    print(i);
    if i in ['l', 'o', 'v' , 'e']:
        print(i);
        t += 1

for i in y:
    print(i);
    if i in ['l', 'o', 'v' , 'e']:
        print(i);
        t += 1

lp = ((len(x) + len(y))*t)
print(f'Love percenatge between [{x.title()}] and [{y.title()}]: {lp:.2f}%')
```

Comment: Works fine for me (it increments `t` and prints stuff out inside the loop).  Did you enter names that contain any of the letters in `love`?  (Remember, it's lowercase -- you might want to lowercase the names right after you `input()` them!)

Comment: btw note that you can just do `i in "love"` instead of typing it out as a list every time!

Comment: Also note that you don't need `;` in Python. Works fine for me with them, but they do not provide a benefit.

Comment: I would say - use IDE to have step-by-step debug. Also there are some not needed characters, but no influence on the result - works for me as well.

Comment: Another note that Python treats strings as lists, so for your purposes `love = "love"` and `love = ['l', 'o', 'v' , 'e']` are equivalent with the former being less verbose and again as @Samwise mentioned you should be using `for I in love`

Comment: What inputs are you providing that aren't working? I imagine you have provided capital letters in which case @Samwise suggestion should work.

Comment: yeah i wasn't entering names with the letter s in them LMAO it did not occur to me, also thank you for the tips greatly appreciate them

Answer (score 1):

To combine the comments into an actionable piece of code:

1. Your code should be functional but your neglect to account for differing cases in letters. In Python `I` and `i` are not equal. ie

```py
'I' == 'i'
=> False
```

2. Python does not require semicolons at the end of lines
3. Python interprets lists and strings equivalently for your use case
4. Your are not using the `love` variable to iterate in your loops

This can be added together to get the following code:

```py
x = input('Enter your name:\n').lower()
y = input('Enter other\'s name:\n').lower()
t = 0
love = "love"
for i in x:
    print(i)
    if i in love:
        print(i)
        t += 1

for i in y:
    print(i)
    if i in love:
        print(i)
        t += 1

lp = ((len(x) + len(y))*t)
print(f'Love percenatge between [{x.title()}] and [{y.title()}]: {lp:.2f}%')
```

Comment: consider using list comprehension too. it can be very useful